# how to set firewall rule/network tag to a google dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to connect to cassandra from google dataflow application. Our Cassandra ring is also on google cloud. When we have to connect to Cassandra through spark on dataproc, we create cluster by passing "--tags cassandra" which allows applications running on dataproc to connect to cassandra. Is there a way to set tags on dataflow ?

Comment: Hi, would you mind elaborating a bit on what you're trying to accomplish?

Do you use the default network? Or have you modified your network settings already? Modifying network settings incorrectly can lead to lots of issues. So I want to get a clear picture of what you've done so far.

Firewall rules are for incoming traffic. So, I think you will need to setup a rule on the Cassandra instance to allow it to receive traffic from the dataflow instances or use the same network. Are they on the same GCP network?

See:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls

Comment: Hi Alex, I do not use default network. I have created another network(Legacy) and I have created a firewall rule that allows communication based on source filter tag as "dataflow" and target tag as "cassandra" with some protocols and ports. I wanted to find out if there is a way to set tag as "dataflow" to my dataflow job. We do the similar thing with dataproc. we have firewall rule that allows communication between source tag "dataproc" and target tag "cassandra". When we create dataproc cluster we pass an argument as --tags dataproc and it works. wanted to find out if we can do the same here

Comment: Just trying to find out if I can avoid giving IP address ranges when I create the firewall rule.

Comment: My cassandra instances are in the same GCP network and are tagged as "cassandra"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would you consider giving this a try, please setup a firewall rule like this:

```
Network: <your cassandra network>
Source Filter: "Instance tags"
Source Tags: "dataflow"
Allowed protocols and ports: <port you use to connect to cassandra>
Target Tags: "cassandra"
```

All GCE VMs launched by the dataflow service should be tagged with "dataflow" by default (Did you see instances without the tag?). So I suspect this will allow traffic from all Dataflow instance to your Cassandra instance.

Hope this works for you

Comment: is it possible to change the tag ? to give something other than dataflow when submitting a job?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, till apache beam version 2.19.0. There is no provision from dataflow to set network tag for its VM. Instead while creating firewall rule, we should add a tag for dataflow. And it is mandatory to give tag name as **dataflow**. Any other tag won't work.
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/routes-firewall

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create FIREWALL_RULE_NAME \
    --network NETWORK \
    --action allow \
    --direction DIRECTION \
    --target-tags dataflow \
    --source-tags dataflow \
    --priority 0 \
    --rules tcp:12345-12346
```

Comment: WHat should be specified for NETWORK?

Comment: @ChaitanyaPatil NETWORK is your VPC name
--network=NETWORK; default="default"
The network to which this rule is attached. If omitted, the rule is attached to the default network.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create